# URL signing using SHA256 key

Tags: php, security

I'm bulding an application using Doctrine ORM and for some reason I need to put a DQL query in a URL. I know.  It's sound like very bad idea but... what if I'll sign URL? I was thinking about something like this:

If my URL is:
`http://example.com/api/?sql=SELECT%20e%20FROM%20SomeEntity`

I can hash this url with some secret:
`$hash = hash('sha256', $url.$someLongSecretToken);`

And finally my URL will be looks like this:
`http://example.com/api/?sql=SELECT%20e%20FROM%20SomeEntity&hash=5639543ff649aa1b799a99d7cbf509a850de5cb31835a22ee7a927560ce33c60`

And after it, just before execute DQL I can remove hash parameter from URL, hash URL again and compare hash form URL with just calculated one. If hashes are same it means that this URL is generated by the server and is not modified.

Is this solution secure? For me as long as sha256 is secure and $someLongSecretToken will be long enough this solution should be secure but I have bad feeling about this ;)

Comment: Putting SQL in the URL is a really, really, reaaaaally bad idea. Even if you are sure that it is completely safe it is a really bad idea. Someone **is** going to find a way to misuse it. Just... don't. And where does it say you have to put it in the URL?!

Comment: Argument "just don't" is not very convincing. If this is secure, why not? The only risk which I noticed so far is that these queires can expose some internal details about system. I know that this sounds like very bad idea and I even noticed this in my question but i came here to find out: "why?".

Comment: If you're going to use a keyed hash construct, and your solution is to concatenate the message with the key, you probably don't know enough about cryptography to make it secure yet.

Comment: See [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) for why this is insecure.  The solution from ircmaxwell is correct.  Despite this, whoever told you to put an SQL query in the URL should be demoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not secure. If a collision attack is found against SHA256, the hash will be able to be faked.

To fix it, replace the hash with a HMAC:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $url, $someLongSecretToken);
```

Definitely use a timing safe comparison:

```
if (hash_equals($signature, hash_hmac('sha256', $url, $secret))) {
    // It's good
}
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but the primary problem is not collision attacks on SHA256.  Instead it is [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

Comment: @TheGreatContini length extension requires the secret to come first, and the attacker-controlled payload to come second. OP's implementation doesn't do that (and hence is immune). However similar techniques could still be used if you can induce a collision in SHA256, hence the answer.

Comment: I think you're right about length extension attacks: it requires payload to come first.  From my memory I am pretty sure there are other attacks against having the secret at the end that are faster than collision attacks, but would have to dig through the research to find them.  This is the reason why HMAC was created.  Note that the only proof that HMAC gives is that it is at least as strong as finding a collision in the hash function, but in practice nobody has done better.  [I once knew this stuff :-)](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/319.pdf)